# Controller action doesn't call if URL parameter is long

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

**FYI: My question is not a duplicate of [404.20 for long url in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798392/404-20-for-long-url-in-mvc-3) so kindly do not confuse.**

I have an Asp.net MVC application where I have a action method which accepts a string type parameter. URL for the same could be very long like below.

```
http://localhost:10537/Search/True_IsFixerUpper/True_IsNewConstruction/True_HasHorses/True_HasVirtualTour/True_HasGarage/True_IsShortSale/True_IsWaterFront/True_HasSwimmingPool/True_HasGolfCourse/True_IsWithinGatedCommunity/True_IsMobileManufacturedHome/True_IsForclosure/True_HasFireplace/True_Is55Community/True_IsWaterfrontRiver/True_IsWaterfrontBay/True_IsWaterfrontInteriorCanal/True_IsWaterfrontOcean/True_IsWaterfrontOceanAccess/True_IsWaterfrontIntracoastal/True_IsWaterfrontLake/True_HasViewOcean/True_HasViewGarden/True_HasViewGolfCourse/True_HasViewRiver/True_HasViewCanal/True_HasViewPond/True_HasViewLake/True_HasViewPool/True_HasPhotos/True_IsOpenHouse/True_IsFenced/True_IsNavigable/True_IsAttached/True_IsDetached/True_IsSemiDetached/True_IsOneStory/True_IsTwoStory/True_IsNonMls/True_IsBoatHouse/True_IsBoatSlip/True_IsDockMooring/
```

Above is giving an error **HTTP Error 404.20 - Not Found**

```
Most likely causes:
    A default document is not configured for the site.
    The URL contains a typographical error.
    Directory browsing is not enabled.

Things you can try:

    Configure a default document for this site. This is commonly default.aspx for ASP.NET and index.php for PHP.
    Review the browser URL.
    Enable directory browsing to allow listing the contents of the directory.
```

while below URLs are working fine.

```
http://localhost:10537/Search?Query=True_IsFixerUpper/True_IsNewConstruction/True_HasHorses/True_HasVirtualTour/True_HasGarage/True_IsShortSale/True_IsWaterFront/True_HasSwimmingPool/True_HasGolfCourse/True_IsWithinGatedCommunity/True_IsMobileManufacturedHome/True_IsForclosure/True_HasFireplace/True_Is55Community/True_IsWaterfrontRiver/True_IsWaterfrontBay/True_IsWaterfrontInteriorCanal/True_IsWaterfrontOcean/True_IsWaterfrontOceanAccess/True_IsWaterfrontIntracoastal/True_IsWaterfrontLake/True_HasViewOcean/True_HasViewGarden/True_HasViewGolfCourse/True_HasViewRiver/True_HasViewCanal/True_HasViewPond/True_HasViewLake/True_HasViewPool/True_HasPhotos/True_IsOpenHouse/True_IsFenced/True_IsNavigable/True_IsAttached/True_IsDetached/True_IsSemiDetached/True_IsOneStory/True_IsTwoStory/True_IsNonMls/True_IsBoatHouse/True_IsBoatSlip/True_IsDockMooring/

http://localhost:10537/Search/True_IsFixerUpper/True_IsNewConstruction/True_HasHorses/True_HasVirtualTour/True_HasGarage
```

**Controller**:

```
public class SearchController : BaseController
{
        public ActionResult Index(string Query)
        {
        }
}
```

**Route**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Search", // Route name
        "Search/{*Query}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", Query = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

What could be problem.

Comment: Could it be that you're missing the "?Query=..." parameter?

Comment: For this, I have created a route. Although it works when URL is not so long, but in case of long url, route doesn't work as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Downvoter: Kindly leave a comment for downvote

Comment: possible duplicate of [404.20 for long url in MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798392/404-20-for-long-url-in-mvc-3)

Comment: @CodeCaster: I tried increasing the maximum url length in web.config, but it didn't help. And my requirement is to post the data using url only. Although the link provided by you also doesn't have any accepted answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster: And as per the answer in that post, Maximum 256 character limit between slashes. But in my case, this is not happening. I do not have even 50 characters between any two consecutive slashes.

Comment: This is simply a bad design. You should send the data in different form. There are many options you could use.

Comment: @Robert: This is not a solution and I'm not looking for any alternate over here. I posted this question because I want to know why it is happening.

Comment: Well I understand, but this is like driving on first gear and then complaining about engine being too hot :)

Comment: @Robert: Problem is with the default maxURLSengments limit which can be modified as explained below. And if you do not understand the query or do not have genuine answer, then atleast do not put a question over architecture. By the way irrelevant example of gear etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because there are too many URL segments in the request.

Check this:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme
                `IIS 8.0 Express returns an HTTP 404.20 error for Too Many URL Segments.`

---

***UPDATE:***

Follow the site below to change the limit of URL segments count.(The default value is 32.)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2012/10/11/iis-8-what-s-new-website-settings.aspx

After changing the configuration, the url will pass the validation of segments count.

Now error will throw about exceeding the maxUrlLength.

You need to add following content to the `<system.web />` section of your ***Web.config*** file.

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="9999" maxQueryStringLength="9999" />
```

Then your long request url with many segments works finally!!!

Comment: Maybe you can try replacing the "/" in your query with other character, such as "+". Then the count of segments will decrease.

Comment: Yes, I can do that as an alternate. I', trying to find out the url segment limit and if somehow i can increase it, that would be great.

Comment: But still I'm wondering that If i put Search?Query= in the url before the parameters, it works. This shows that it is not the issue related with URL Segment length/limit. Any suggestion?

Comment: It look likes a problem with Routing, because it is working fine if i make url with actual query parameter but didn't work as per routing.

Comment: The "/" in request query part is not used to calculate the count of the segment. The query part is only used to bind parameters. Keep you posted when I find where to change the limit.

Comment: I tried appcmd set config /section:requestfiltering /requestlimits.maxquerystring:4096 command to change the limit but it didn't work. FYI: I'm running my application in VS2013 now, it's not been deployed on IIS yet.

Comment: I find the solution! Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Great, It looks good but I can't test it. I am running my website in Visual Studio 2013. Can you please tell me where should i get this option to change maximum url segments.

Comment: What I was doing is to deploy the site with IIS and then I can change the IIS settings. You can follow following site to config your site. It seems can be done by appcmd. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits

Comment: In the "Web" tab of "Properties" of the project, you can change the "Servers" from "IIS Express" to "Local IIS". Then you can make it work by changing the IIS settings.

Comment: Problem resolved automatically when I hosted my application on IIS (7.5). It's not giving me any error related to maxUrlSegments limit. Problem is only when I run the project in Visual Studio, after hosting it's working fine.