# How do I configure the maximum subdirectory depth in IIS?

Tags: iis, url-routing, iis-8

I'm running an ASP.NET service on IIS8 and I'm running into an error I wasn't expecting.
When fed a URL like 
`example.com/144/299/322/400/511/622/733/844/977/101/119/127/130/144/153/162/172/183/195/207/210/221/235/242/255/261/274/287/296/304/314/326` (32 levels deep) it is perfectly happy.

`example.com/144/299/322/400/511/622/733/844/977/101/119/127/130/144/153/162/172/183/195/207/210/221/235/242/255/261/274/287/296/304/314/326/335` (33 levels deep) gets me an IIS error. I can remove the final slash and add more characters, so it's not a URL length limitation.

The IIS error information is not terribly useful:

- Module: IIS Web Core
- Notification: BeginRequest
- Handler: Not yet determined
- Error Code: 0x00000000

And all my Googling has led me to believe that no one else has ever run into this limit, which seems strange and unlikely so I'm guessing that I am using entirely incorrect terminology.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controller action doesn't call if URL parameter is long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861467/controller-action-doesnt-call-if-url-parameter-is-long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Maximum Url Segments limit in IIS 8 is defined as 32. Anything longer will return an error.

The link below will assist you in finding and updating this setting for whatever is appropriate for your site.

[IIS 8.0 What's New - Website Settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2012/10/11/iis-8-what-s-new-website-settings.aspx)

Comment: Note that this isn't something that can be (easily) set through configuration files, but instead could be scripted though PowerShell.

Comment: Any idea if the limit is different in IIS 7?